# struggling to install PHP pecl on Centos

Tags: php, linux, centos, pecl

I'm trying to install the `php_http` PHP extension on my CentOS server.

I have done:

```
yum install php-pear
```

But get:

```
No package php-pear available
```

Yet I can do:

```
pear
```

And get a list of commands from Pear.

Same for `yum install pecl`. I can do `pecl` but `pecl install pecl_http` returns:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"
install failed
```

Yet `/usr/bin/pecl` isn't a directory that exists. Also a `sudo pecl install pecl_http` returns `sudo: pecl: command not found`, which I find quite odd.

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here/what I'm doing wrong.

edit: I am using the following repos:

```
base                         CentOS-6 - Base
epel                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
extras                       CentOS-6 - Extras
rpmforge                     RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag
updates                      CentOS-6 - Updates
vz-base                      vz-base
vz-updates                   vz-updates
```

Comment: What repositories are you using?

Comment: @BenCarey I have edited my question to include some output of `yum repolist`.

Comment: This really is a [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) question. I can't see a programming question here at all, no offence.

Comment: @gwillie Feel free to flag it for migration, then.

Comment: On CentOS 7 I used: `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-pear php-devel`

Answer (score 15):

On CentOS,

1. Install PHP Pear if not installed yet:

   ```
   # yum install php-pear
   ```
2. Install GCC if not installed yet:

   ```
   # yum install gcc
   ```
3. Install cURL if not installed yet:

   ```
   # yum install curl-devel
   ```
4. Install following libraries if not installed yet:

   ```
   # yum install php-devel
   # yum install zlib-devel
   # yum install pcre-devel
   ```
5. Start the main installation:

   ```
   # pecl install pecl_http
   ```
6. Add the following line to /etc/php.ini file

   ```
   extension=raphf.so
   extension=propro.so
   extension=http.so
   ```
7. Restart apache server so the extension can be loaded

   ```
   # service httpd restart
   ```

You can check if it installed successfully or not:

```
# pecl list
```

Comment: If the newest version 2.x of pecl not work, uninstall it by pecl uninstall pecl_http, then install older version by pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6, it works properlly.

Answer (score 10):

Step 1) import the REMI repo

**CentOS 5**

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm;
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm;
```

**CentOS 6**

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm;
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm;
```

Step 2) install php-pear

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pear
```

Step 3) install pecl_http

```
pecl install pecl_http
```

Comment: I added the REMI repo and tried to install php-pear but it still can't find the package. I should add, I'm using PHP 5.4.19

Comment: on step 2, it says 'No package php-pear available.' any suggestions please ?

Comment: @Dashrath try `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php5-pear`

Answer (score 6):

For other people having this problem.  I discovered this question while trying to figure out why I was having the same problem.  Turned out the default configuration at my hosting provider was to include `php*` in the `exclude` directive for yum.  Check `/etc/yum.conf` and make sure that the package you're trying to install isn't matched by an entry in the `exclude` directive.

Comment: I was migrating a site on bluehost and this seemed to be the situation too. The service is normally all managed with whm / cpanel so there must be something to do with this.

Answer (score 6):

if you are running php 7 you might want to try this

```
yum install php70w-pear
```

if you get any errors, be sure to uninstall the pear package from any previous attempts

```
yum remove php-pear
```

best of luck

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php 5.4.x, IMO best repo to use is iuscommunity.  Its very stable and used by Rackspace to do only PHP and a few other packages for CentOS.

rpm -Uhv http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm

yum install php54-pear

Mind you, the reason why its php54-pear and not php-pear is because 5.3 and 5.4 both are compiled in the repository. Here is the list of php packages -> http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/repoview/development.languages.group.html

I tested this and it works, but I only use EPEL and iuscommunity REPO's. I avoid using rpmforge myself.

Comment: I just tried that and I still get `no package php54-pear available`.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Because the package is in the repo.  You can always do this rpm -Uhv http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/php54-pear-1.9.4-2.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm

Comment: Same result. To be honest I'm not bothered anymore. So yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Centos 6.5 and php7:

```
sudo su -

yum install yum-utils
```

## you can get last version of lua : http://pecl.php.net/package/lua

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/lua-2.0.4.tgz

tar -xvzf  lua-2.0.4.tgz

cd lua-2.0.4

mkdir  /usr/include/lua

mv * /usr/include/lua

yum install gcc

yum install php70w-pearl php70w-devel



yum install curl-devel

yum install zlib-devel

yum install pcre-devel

ln -s /usr/include/lua.h /usr/include/lua/lua.h

rpm -Uvh https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70

yum update 

yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 install php70w-pear

yum install lua-devel lua-static

pecl install lua-2.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your PHP provider is (IUS, Remi or Webtatic), the pear package and the pecl extensions "should" be available there, without any need to compile it from sources (which is usually discouraged, especially on production)

At least "remi" provides most extensions, see [the list](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status)

So installation should be as simple as

```
yum install php-pecl-http
yum install php-pecl-lua
etc
```

And, don't forget to read the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost everything on this list before I finally realized that my WHM/cPanel installation was blocking the yum packages. I have to install all PECL modules (I was stuck trying to install mongodb on this particular occation) through the **Home > Software > Module Installers** inside WHM (cpanel documentation says that [you have to be logged in as root](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/software/php-pecl/)).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these I still can't get pecl installed.
I am running CentOS

"No package php-pecl-mongo available."

These are the types of errors I get

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35299615)

Answer (score -1):

After watching a lot of threads and installing pear and all the devtool, I finally solved it installing this extension:

```
yum install php-pecl-mongo
```

as I seen in - https://madcoda.com/2012/12/install-mongodb-php-driver-in-centos-6-3/