# Install gRPC on centOS / Plesk

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, plesk

I'm stuck for a couple of hours now, I want to use Cloud Fire store on domains on my Plesk Server, but I can't get it to work.
I followed the steps from https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc 
and a lot of other tutorials, but on all I get errors.

I managed to update the OS PHP version of CentOS, but still no luck. 
What I want is that PHP Version 7.2.14 works with gRPC (I already added extension=grpc.so to the php.ini) 
But there really isn't a any good documentation on Plesk and gRPC

Comment: shared code what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting? It's during installing grpc.so or it's installed but the script can't load it?
Also, from the link you give, "CentOS/RHEL 6" is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

In my case help this

1. Install Pecl PHP for CentOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/31558558/1932494
2. Then run:  pecl install grpc